# Rails Grape api versioning module structure

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, versioning, ruby-grape, grape-api

I'm trying to implement api versioning, almost the same as [I've done here](https://github.com/Asmmund/grape_versioning) . but i don't seem to get module/folder structure right in rails app, because I get error messages like `V1 is not a module /app/api/v1/xml_responses/device.rb:3:in '<module:API>'`
Directory structure

```
/app
  /api
    - api.rb
    /v1
      -base.rb
      /xml_responces
        - device.rb
```

**api.rb**

```
require 'v1/base.rb'
module  API
  class Base < Grape::API
    mount API::V1 => '/v1/'
  end
end
```

**v1/base.rb**

```
module API
  module V1
  class ApiV1 < Grape::API
    require 'builder'
    helpers DeviceMethods
    prefix 'api'
    version 'v1', using: :header
  end
  end
end
```

**V1/xml_responses/device.rb**

```
module API
  module V1
    module XMLResponses::Device
      def self.do_something
        #do_something
      end
    end
  end
end
```

**Routes.rb**

```
  mount API::Base => '/'
```

I can't figure out what i'm doing wrong! could you please help me?

Comment: Try requiring v1/base.rb at the top of your device.rb file.

Comment: Nope, this didn't help

Comment: Still the same module error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was having similar problems, but then stumbled on this great post that helped me get things to work, and had more complete information than I found elsewhere. See http://funonrails.com/2014/03/building-restful-api-using-grape-in-rails/

Looking at your code, this looks funny:

```
module XMLResponses::Device
  def self.do_something
```

Do you mean to do something like this?

```
module API
  module V1
    module XMLResponses
      class Device < Grape::API
        resource :device do
          get do { Device.all } # Or whatever
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have this line in `application.rb`

```
config.paths.add "app/api", glob: "**/*.rb"
config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{Rails.root}/app/api/*"]
```

As suggested at grape wiki [here.](https://github.com/dpsk/grape#rails)